# Assigning a Page Directive Meta:ResourceKey on code generated .resx?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, localization, resx

I'm having issues with pages that were given `.resxs` via code. I've been unable to find any way to assign a page directive `meta:resourcekey` (and actually link the page to the `.resx`). When I used the "Generate Local Resource" function to create a page's `.resx;` the page directive was given the following: `Meta:ResourceKey="PageResource1"` and the .resxs for that page were linked (somehow).

> ([Design Mode] > <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Generate Local Resource</kbd>)

I've tried manually assigning page resources to no avail. I can't seem to find a solution to link the generated .resx files to their respective pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated.